# How to call a macro on send button click?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that takes the description of an email that I've selected and populates the "message" field of a form that is created from a template:

```
sText = olItem.Body

Set msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\template.oft")
With msg
   .Subject = "Test"
   .To = "user@user.com"
   'Set body format to HTML
   .BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>EmailDesc: " + sText + "</BODY></HTML>"
   .Display
End With
```

In this template, I have more fields to fill, like combobox.. for example.

I would like to know, how do I get the value of this combo when I click on the send button, and concatenate it to the contents of the email before sending?

Generating something like this:

```
EmailDesc: TEST SEND EMAIL BLA BLA BLA..
ComboboxValue: Item1
```

Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Application_ItemSend event` which fires when you press send button. You create this event in `ThisOutlookSession module`. Your event sub could look like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    With Item   'Item is your e-mail
        'this way you could change your subject just before you send message
        .Subject = "test subject"   
        'here some changes regarding body of the message
        .Body = .Body & " Additional text at the end or " & _
                "ComboBoxValue: " '& ... reference to combobox value here
    End With

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error!"
End Sub
```

Be careful- this will make action to each of your e-mail therefore you should add some `if statements` to make it works only with some of your e-mails.

Comment: how can I get selected combobox value?