# Attaching an event handler to an Outlook.MailItem that was programmatically created

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm writing an Outlook 2010 macro in VBA that replies to email but doesn't automatically *send* the email. Instead, the macro simply displays the email so that I can review its contents before clicking the "Send" button.

However, I'd like this first macro to attach another macro that runs when I hit the "Send" button in the Inspector. While I'm able to respond to Application-level send events easily (using `Application_ItemSend()` as discussed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569372/how-to-call-a-macro-on-send-button-click)), I'd prefer to attach the second macro solely to the programmatically generated reply so that it applies only to the emails I created with the macro itself, rather than all email. Is this possible?

More specifically, I have a regular module in my project that does something like this (simplified):

```
Public Sub replyToEmail()
    Dim responseMail As Outlook.MailItem, originalEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim myHandler as New replyHandler
    Set responseMail = originalEmail.reply
    ' do something and set responseMail.Body intelligently, then
    Set myHandler.reply = responseMail ' <-- WHY DOESN'T THIS PERSIST?
    responseMail.Display ' Show me the email so I can review it
End Sub
```

I also have a class module for my automated responses, `replyHandler`, something like this:

```
Public WithEvents reply As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub reply_Send(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Do additional processing upon Send event
    ' but why doesn't this ever get called, despite "reply" being set in the subroutine above?
End Sub
```

It's this class module I'm having trouble with, because it seems like no matter what I try in the first macro, the `reply_Send()` Sub never gets executed. That is, my question is how do I get that Sub to run after `replyToEmail()` runs? Or put another way, how do I persist the reference to `responseMail` in `replyToEmail()` so that my class module's `reply_Send()` event handler is actually called when I click on the "Send" button of the message that `replyToEmail()` created and displays?

Is there any way to do this without attaching a global Application-level ItemSend handler?

The [Microsoft Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865379(v=office.14).aspx) provides some guidance but its example requires that a third macro be run after the response email is created and before I click the Inspector's Send button. (It reads: "The sample code must be placed in a class module such as `ThisOutlookSession`, and the `SendMyMail` procedure must be called before the event procedure can be called by Microsoft Outlook.") I'd rather do this step automatically, too. But, again, how can I persist the reference to the programmatically created MailItem across the two `Sub`routines?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT TO CLARIFY SOLUTION:

The issue here turned out to be variable scope. Instead of `Dim myHandler as New replyHandler` within the subroutine itself, this should be declared at module-level as `Public myHandler As New replyHandler`. Then, the line later on that executes `Set myHandler.reply = responseMail` correctly persists the `myHandler.reply` variable across to the second subroutine.

Comment: Are you creating an instance of the sunk class that you are aiming the events on, not just using a mail item ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then I tried doing both. I created an instance of the class module and set its `.reply` member to the MailItem returned from the `originalEmail.reply` method as well as simply trying to save the MailItem in a public member of the regular module. Neither worked, and I'm not sure why. Maybe Outlook releases the object references of the regular module when the macro reaches End Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly handle events for all Outlook items or specific items, you need to manage a collection of Inspector Wrappers.  The basic idea is capture the Inspectors.NewInspector event and create your wrapper if this is an item you want to capture (e.g. an e-mail in compose mode).  Each individual wrapper will have its own container of events.  See this article for a good explanation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973716.aspx

Otherwise, when you first create the reply item you can get a handle to the new compose email that's returned by the Reply method, and start handling the events just for that item.  So you can trap MailItem.Send and cancel it if you need to, and that event will only fire as long as the new reply email is alive. No other items will fire that specific event.  You just need to make sure that you declare a module level variable with Public scope (and using WithEvents) for the item that you want to expose events for.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the Inspectors, but this method still relies on creating a global event handler, to "capture the Inspectors.NewInspector event" right? That's exactly what I want to avoid.

Also, you perfectly *describe* what I'm trying to do in your "Otherwise," block, but you don't actually explain any detail of how to go about this. I *know* that I can get a handle to the new compose email. My question is how to persist this handle, generated from inside one subroutine, so that it can be used to trap the MailItem.Send event associated with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eric, I've edited the code in my question to try to clarify the question about the code I'm trying to use.

Comment: I see the problem: your replyHandler class will work, BUT you are trying to set an object to myHandler.reply; the reply field is private and should actually throw a compile error (I think).  Change that to a public property/field in that class and it should work.

Comment: Sorry Eric, my mistake in copying and pasting. The myHandler member is public. I *also* tried a private property with a setter, like `Public Sub setHandledItem(item As Outlook.MailItem) Set reply = item End Sub`, and then called this handler class's Sub from the first Sub, but this failed, too. So, no, the visibility of the members is not the problem (I'll correct the code above). And this is what I tried first, but my question remains: if this *should* work (it was the first thing I tried), what could be causing this not to work?

Comment: Try declaring myHandler in the module scope

Comment: Eric, that did it! *THANK YOU.* So this means that the Sub's variables are garbage collected on End Sub after all, yes? I'll gladly accept your answer if you edit it to note that persisting the variables requires a module-level variable rather than a Sub-level one. Again, my thanks for your time.