# Pop-Up every time after sending an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-office

I would like to get a pop-up window, every time I send an email. In this window, I need to write down an ID and an amount of time that shall be saved in excel document.

I have never ever worked in Outlook VBA so I have actually no idea how to start :(

In the end, every time I click on send email, there should a pop-up appear where I enter the Id and the time I was working on it and the data should be saved in excel.

Thanks to everyone that understands what I mean and maybe can help me a little bit...

Comment: Outlook fires an event when a mail gets sent.
[How to call a macro on send button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569372/how-to-call-a-macro-on-send-button-click)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Application.ItemSend` event - the message being sent will be passed to your event handler. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend

Comment: Thank you, I will try it rn

Comment: I have copied the example code from this site into my outlook vba just to have a start, but nothing is happening when i write an email? :(

Comment: You really needs to start a new thread and post the relevant snippets of your code.